# What's wrong with my computer?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, windows-update

I use Windows-7 64 bit. Since the beginning of using my computer I have 3 problems:

1. I [can't use Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/305379/google-chrome-doesnt-work-in-windows-7-64-bit). It just doesn't load my websites. And at first it caused blue screen.
2. I can't update my Windows, because when I run Windows Update it just doesn't load my startup and I have to restore my Windows.
3. [Hibernate doesn't work](https://superuser.com/questions/300212/hibernate-doesnt-work-in-windows-7-64bit) unless I tried everything to fix it.

I think I have one problem which causes everything. Any ideas? I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you bluescreened would make me think that you have either a driver issue, or a hardware issue, and in this case, since you are having so many problem, I would think hardware issue.

I would look at these links, and run a hardware diagnostic, or if go to your manufacturer's web site and see if they have one specifically for their hardware (Dell does, for example).

https://superuser.com/questions/43846/recommendations-for-hardware-diagnostic-software-bootable

https://superuser.com/questions/104235/what-is-the-best-hardware-diagnostic-for-a-pc

Ultimate boot CD has a lot of proponents on this site.

If you pass the hardware tests, run `sfc /scannow` from a command line to make sure your Windows files are intact, and then update all your drivers and run Windows Update.